# ¿Expresión regular en flex para los elementos de tipo Char en Java?

Tags: java, regex, jflex, cup

Estoy haciendo un minicompilador en ***CUP*** y ***JFLEX*** pero no sé que expresión regular satisface el conjunto de los Char.

La especificación del conjunto que me ha dado el profesor es la siguiente:

> Se permite la definición de constantes y variables de tipo char. Para las constantes se emplea la misma sintaxis que en Java, usando comillas simples, (por ejemplo `'a'`) y pudiendo usar las secuencias de escape al igual que en Java para los caracteres especiales `('\b','\n','\f','\r','\t','\"','\\','\'')`, así como secuencias en Unicode (por ejemplo `'\u1234'`).

Es decir que el conjunto de elementos que me tiene que coger la expresión regular es `'\n', '&', 'a', 'u0043'`, etc.

He usado esta expresión regular pero no me ha funcionado:

```
("'"."'") | "'"(‘\b’,’\n’,’\f’,’\r’,’\t’,’\”’,’\\’,’\’’)"'" | ("'"'\u'[0-9]+"'")
```

¿Alguien puede sugerirme otra expresión regular?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], es muy importante que leas [ask]. Adicional seria mejor que en vez de subir imagenes coloques la expresion regular y el enunciado que te dejo el profesor en formato texto, para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa hecho

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
'(\\(["'\\bfnrt]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|[^\\'])'
```

Visualmente:

[image: visual]

En Java se recomienda definir una constante de `Pattern` para mejorar la eficiencia:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("\'(\\\\([\"\'\\\\bfnrt]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|[^\\\\\'])\'");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "\'\\n\', \'&\', \'a\', \'\\u0043\', \'\"\'";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
'\n'
'&'
'a'
'\u0043'
'"'
```